# No puedo enviar correos por Squirrelmail (Postfix y dovecot)

Tags: linux, webservice, ubuntu, email

estoy instalando un servidor de correos en Ubuntu server 14.01.5. en una maquina virtual.
El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero enviar un correo por ejemplo; de usuario1 a usuario2, al darle clic en enviar no sucede nada, los correos no salen. Estuve investigando un poco y al revisar el archivo /var/log/mail.log encontré los siguientes errores
[image: /var/log/mail.log]

Es la primera vez que quiero instalar un servidor de correo, así que tal vez allá echo algo mal.
archivo /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = colegiocolosio.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = colegiocolosio.com, server, localhost.localdomain, localhost
realyhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```